# For a prime $p$ if $p^m = p^n+2\cdot p^k$ then $p=3$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

I read an article on commuting graphs of groups and at some point, author gets the equality $|\langle x,Z\rangle| = |Z|\cup 2\cdot |x^G|$ where $Z$ denotes the center of the $p$-group $G$ and $x^G$ denotes the conjugacy class containing $x$. From this equality he gets $p=3$.

Since $G$ is a $p$-group, $\langle x,Z\rangle, |Z|, |x^G|$ are all $p$-powers. First, I thought this is a number theoretic result but then realised it is not true since for $p=2$, we have infinitely many solutions.

Thus I am not sure how the author get this equality. If only solutions are $p=2$ or $p=3$, then I guess using some other results it is possible to eliminate $p=2$ case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's notice $m \gt k, m \gt n$.

Suppose $n \gt k$ and simplify by $p^k$. We get $p^{m-k}=p^{n-k} + 2$ so $p | 2$ therefore $p=2$.

Now suppose $n=k$, then $p^{m-k}=3$ therefore $p=3$.

I leave the case $k \gt n$ to you, it's easy to prove there is no $p$ for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $m\ge n$ and $m\ge k$ If $k\lt n$ then $p^{m-k}=p^{n-k}+2$ impossible. If $k\gt n$ then $p^{m-n}=1+2p^{n-k}$ impossible. If $k=n$ then $p^{m-n}=1+2$ which admets the solution $p=3$ (with $m=n+1$).